# Could Insufficient Funds error mean the signature is incorrect? - using golang and raw transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, raw-transaction, golang, ecdsa

I want to sign a transaction "offline" without using crypto.sign.
The code looks like the following:

```
unsignedTx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, to, amount, gasLimit, gasPrice, nil)

networkID := big.NewInt(3) //Ropsten
signer := types.NewEIP155Signer(networkID)

unsignedTxJSON, err := unsignedTx.MarshalJSON() 
    
unsignedTxBin, err := unsignedTx.MarshalBinary() 
ethMessage := fmt.Sprintf("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n%d%s", len(unsignedTxBin), unsignedTxBin)
    
hashedEthMessage := crypto.Keccak256([]byte(ethMessage))
    
hsmSignedResult, err := signFromHsm(p, session, privateKeyHandle, hashedEthMessage)

   ... some conversion from point to big ints later ...

if hsmBigIntS.Cmp(secp256k1halfN) < 0 && hsmBigIntR.Cmp(secp256k1N) < 0 {
// (s) is LESS than curve.n/2+1 and (r) less than curve.n so v=0 + y%2

x := new(big.Int)
two := big.NewInt(2)
vInt64 := int64(0) + x.Mod(pubKey.Y, two).Int64()

newSignature := append(hsmSignedResult, byte(vInt64))

attemptedRecoveredPub, err := crypto.Ecrecover(hashedEthMessage, []byte(newSignature))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

fmt.Printf("\The public key was recovered from signature so we can now proceed to send the tx\n")

signedTx, err := unsignedTx.WithSignature(signer, newSignature)
signedTxJSON, err := signedTx.MarshalJSON()

fmt.Printf("\nSignedTx: %s\n", signedTxJSON)

//standard call using client.SendTransaction(ctx, tx) that always fails with
// panic: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
sendRawTx(signedTx) 

}
```

I doubt it's related to the gas, but these are the values:
Gas limit: 100000
Gas price: 1708100000
ETH Amount: 0.1 ETH

An example of a transaction generated is:
SignedTx:

```
{"type":"0x0","nonce":"0x1","gasPrice":"0x65cf89a0","gas":"0x186a0","value":"0x2386f26fc10000","input":"0x","v":"0x2a","r":"0xcb80f65ff3a7298470de46d36995418517efbf2590b246c59c0300a21188196b","s":"0x3a75a0ef6b3a694f80529d719380c12d169612b6b0c04e0f13f1b6c8e40747fc","to":"0x3e363a6ab5336a41121629b38a6d3b0ee7384a6e","hash":"0xd8b62a843ab8f1df6d3f3aef3c223740a5ce546d1a21a428efc651c5b1742013"}
```

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing? Could it be related to the way I generated V?

Any indication would be appreciated

Comment: Probably I'm wrong or you just did it before, but did you test your code in a local network instead of using Ropsten?

Comment: Transactions aren't signed with the "Ethereum" prefix just the rpl representation is signed. Decode the signed transaction with https://flightwallet.github.io/decode-eth-tx/ to calculate from.